# change path for spark dataframe partition writing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing dataframe with partitionBy(part_column) which writes it in output directory with partitions as output_dir/part_column_name=part_value.

Is it any way possible to write in format of output_dir/part_value ?

Current code looks as below

```
dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").partitionBy(part_column).save(outputPath)
```

Suppose my partition column is dt. dt has values '20180701','20180702'.
If I execute

```
dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").partitionBy("dt").save("/etl/output").
```

It will create output directories as /etl/output/dt=20180701 and /etl/output/dt=20180702

But I want it to be /etl/output/20180701 and /etl/output/20180702

Thanks

Comment: Didn’t get your question. Please elaborate. You are saving the data in a path in the part_column value as folder. What is your expected output. Give an example

Comment: @Chandan Updated the question

Answer (score 3):

As per spark documentation this is the desired behaviour and there is no option in spark api to change the directory layout.

Please see below url and check partitionBy api

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html

If you need to change the layout then you can use shell script and Hadoop HDFS command to move the file to a new directory.